# Python - Make a matrix but fill the columns first - ADFGVX

Tags: python, matrix, encryption

I'm doing a ADFGVX cipher decoder and I need to make a matrix from a text but I want the matrix to be made in columns and not in rows but keeping the same length.

I have this text: `XXVFVAGFFGXD`

The length of the matrix is set from len("testes").

And I can create this matrix:

| x | x | v | f | v | a |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| g | f | f | g | x | d |

But what i want is:

| x | v | v | g | f | x |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| x | f | a | f | g | d |

I dont know how its possible to do this way.

Let me know if its bad explained.

Comment: Could you please reword/reformat this? This is difficult to follow. I can't tell if the same paragraph is just repeating the same thing twice or if I'm misunderstanding.

Comment: @EwanBrown Sry i wrote thye same thing 2 times

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My first thought would be to use `numpy`:

```
import numpy as np
x = 'XXVFVAGFFGXD'
matrix = np.array(list(x)).reshape((6, 2)).transpose()
print(matrix)
```

Which gives

```
array([['X', 'V', 'V', 'G', 'F', 'X'],
       ['X', 'F', 'A', 'F', 'G', 'D']], dtype='<U1')
```

The key here is that you want columns filled first instead of rows, and `transpose` has the effect of swapping rows and columns, so we need only add the reshape command to complete the result.

Comment: Is there any way not to use numpy. It is for a college project and my professor won't let me use numpy. Thanks anyway

Comment: I edited the post because I forgot to tell how the lenght of each row is defined